# I want to receive push notification using parse and display it in an activity. How can I get the values from parse notification?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I tried this to save a push

```
ParseQuery parseq=ParseInstallation.getQuery();
parseq.whereEqualTo("role", "manager");

ParseObject p=ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();

ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
push.setQuery(parseq);
push.setMessage("My measage");
push.sendInBackground();
```

Now I want to get my message after receiving notification and get the response printed in an activity.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do following for getting the value from push notification.

1. Add the ParsePushReciever in your main package.

   ```
   import android.app.NotificationManager;
   import android.app.PendingIntent;

   import android.content.Context;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
   import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;


   import com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver;


   public class ParsePushReciever extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {


   @Override
   public void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
       AppLog.e("Push", "Clicked");
       Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
       i.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
       i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       context.startActivity(i);
   }

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       Log.d("Push Notification",intent.getExtras().get(ParsePushBroadcastReceiver.KEY_PUSH_DATA).toString());
       NotificationManager nm=(NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

       NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

       builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.launcher);

       Intent newIntent=new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
       newIntent.putExtra(context.getString(R.string.navigation_from_notification),true);
       newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
               Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
       PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, newIntent, 0);

       builder.setContentIntent(pi);

       builder.setContentText("Push Notification");

       Log.d("Notification", strMsg);

       nm.notify(1, builder.build());
   }
   }
   ```
2. Add the reciever in your manifest file:

   ```
   <receiver android:name=".ParsePushReciever" android:exported="false" >
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
           <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
           <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
       </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
   <meta-data
       android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon"
       android:resource="@drawable/launcher" />
   ```
3. Check for notification in your MainActivity:

   ```
   if(getIntent()!=null) {

       if (getIntent().getExtras()!=null &&
           getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean(getString(R.string.navigation_from_notification))) {

          //get data from intent and display it in your activity.
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: ParsePushBroadcastReceiver  class not fount in library please help

Answer (score 0):

This little code can get all the text from a push, you can do your things with it:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
super.onReceive(context, intent);
JSONObject json = null;
try {
    json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));
    String text = json.getString("alert").toString();
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

just put it inside your onReceive() method of your ParsePushBroadcastReceiver.

I hope this help you.