# Save push notification content from parse.com into a local database

Tags: android, parse-platform, sqlite

I am building an android app that allow users to receive notifications every day. I send the notification message from parse.com to every user of the app.  The app works correctly by receiveing the notifications everyday. Now the problem is storing every notification into a local database, so that a user can read the notification at anytime. The notification content should be stored into the database as soon as the notification is released from parse.com, whether the user clicks to view it or not.

I would be grateful if anyone would direct me to use the correct method. Thanks

Comment: please go through this link : http://stackoverflow.com/a/30681249/1944782

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own subclass of `ParsePushBroadcastReceiver` and register it in the `AndroidManifest`, override `onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)` method. Then in this method you can extract content of push message using this code

```
@Override
protected void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onPushOpen(context, intent);
    JSONObject data = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));
}
```

Then all you need to do is to store push data and show it somehow. For example you can create new ParseObject, for example **PushMessage** (don't forget to call `Parse.registerSubclass()` in the `onCreate()` in your Application class) and pin it to `LocalDataStore`. And then when you need to show all received notifications you can create ListView and ParseQuery, query all **PushMessage** objects from `LocalDataStore` and display them in ListView.